# Using mongo with docker and nfs storage

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-volume

I have a glusterfs that works fine when i create a volume on Cent7 using: `docker volume create...` and providing the type as nfs, here is the full command I use to create the volume:

> docker volume create --name sv1_mongovol1 --opt type=nfs --opt device=:/root/gluster/mounts --opt o=addr=172.23.180.79

The above volume works perfectly if I use an "alpine" container or sth similar and mount it, the files i touch/create, get written to remove storage, but when I launch a mongo container, it fails. This is how I am launching:

> docker run --privileged --rm -it -p 27017:27017 -v sv1_mongovol1:/data/db --name mongodb mongo

And here is the error log

```
017-02-26T02:31:00.391+0000 I STORAGE [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock No locks available. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2017-02-26T02:31:00.391+0000 I NETWORK [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-02-26T02:31:00.391+0000 I NETWORK [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-02-26T02:31:00.391+0000 I CONTROL [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-02-26T02:31:00.391+0000 I CONTROL [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

I posted here also:
https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/30